GAN with MaskedSelfAttentionLayer : Loading .keras file could not load some objects
I'm currently implementing GAN in which I want to use MaskedSelfAttention for an Inpainting task. For this I implemented my the architecture, can train it but when I want to restore the saved models (save them after each epoch) to inpaint in the images the following objects could not be loaded:
[<Conv2D name=conv2d_18, built=False>, <Conv2D name=conv2d_17, built=False>, <Conv2D name=conv2d_19, built=False>, <MaskedSelfAttention name=masked_self_attention, built=True>]
this is my current system - I reduce the view to the Architecture and the saving, loading and instanciation part. When something is missing feel free to ask:
import tensorflow as tf
# Get a list of available GPUs
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')

# Ensure that at least one GPU is available
if physical_devices:
   
    print("GPU memory fully allocated")
else:
    print("No GPU found.")

import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array, load_img
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose, Concatenate, LeakyReLU, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, load_model
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.saving import register_keras_serializable
import os
import time
import yaml
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class MaskedSelfAttention(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, channels, **kwargs):
        super(MaskedSelfAttention, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.channels = channels
        # Define layers for query, key, and value
        self.query = layers.Conv2D(channels // 8, kernel_size=1)
        self.key = layers.Conv2D(channels // 8, kernel_size=1)
        self.value = layers.Conv2D(channels, kernel_size=1)
        self.gamma = self.add_weight(name="gamma", shape=(), initializer="zeros", trainable=True)

    def call(self, x, mask):
        shape = tf.shape(x)
        batch_size, height, width, channels = shape[0], shape[1], shape[2], shape[3]

        query = tf.reshape(self.query(x), (batch_size, height * width, -1))
        key = tf.reshape(self.key(x), (batch_size, -1, height * width))

        attention = tf.nn.softmax(
            tf.matmul(query, key) / tf.math.sqrt(tf.cast(height * width, tf.float32)), axis=-1
        )

        value = tf.reshape(self.value(x), (batch_size, height * width, -1))
        out = tf.matmul(attention, value)

        out = tf.reshape(out, (batch_size, height, width, channels))
        out = self.gamma * out + x

        out = out * mask + x * (1 - mask)
        return out

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(MaskedSelfAttention, self).get_config()
        config.update({'channels': self.channels})
        return config

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        # Restore custom layer using the provided configuration
        return cls(**config)

    def get_build_config(self):
        # Return configuration needed for rebuilding the layer (optional)
        return {'channels': self.channels}

    def build_from_config(self, config):
        # Rebuild the layer from config
        self.__init__(**config)


@register_keras_serializable()
class Generator(Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()

        self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
            layers.ReLU(),
            layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
            layers.BatchNormalization(),
            layers.ReLU(),
            layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
            layers.BatchNormalization(),
            layers.ReLU(),
        ])

        self.middle_attention = MaskedSelfAttention(256)

        self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential([
            layers.Conv2DTranspose(128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
            layers.BatchNormalization(),
            layers.ReLU(),
            layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
            layers.BatchNormalization(),
            layers.ReLU(),
            layers.Conv2D(1, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="same"),
            layers.Activation("sigmoid"),
        ])

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # Ensure that encoder, middle_attention, and decoder layers are built
        self.encoder.build(input_shape)
        
        # Build the middle_attention layer with the appropriate input shape
        attention_input_shape = (None, input_shape[1] // 4, input_shape[2] // 4, 256)
        self.middle_attention.build(attention_input_shape)
        
        # Build the decoder with the output shape from attention layer
        decoder_input_shape = attention_input_shape
        self.decoder.build(decoder_input_shape)

        super(Generator, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x, mask):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        encoded_shape = tf.shape(x)
        mask_resized = tf.image.resize(mask, size=(encoded_shape[1], encoded_shape[2]))
        mask_broadcasted = tf.broadcast_to(mask_resized, tf.shape(x))
        x = self.middle_attention(x, mask_broadcasted)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(Generator, self).get_config()
        config.update({
            'encoder': self.encoder.get_config(),
            'middle_attention': self.middle_attention.get_config(),
            'decoder': self.decoder.get_config(),
        })
        return config

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        encoder = tf.keras.Sequential.from_config(config['encoder'])
        middle_attention = MaskedSelfAttention.from_config(config['middle_attention'])
        decoder = tf.keras.Sequential.from_config(config['decoder'])

        model = cls()
        model.encoder = encoder
        model.middle_attention = middle_attention
        model.decoder = decoder
        return model

# Discriminator
class Discriminator(Model):
    def __init__(self, IMG_HEIGHT=512, IMG_WIDTH=512):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        
        # Resize input image to fixed size (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH)
        self.resize = layers.Resizing(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH)

        # Define the Sequential model for the Discriminator
        self.model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
            layers.LeakyReLU(0.2),
            layers.Conv2D(128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
            layers.BatchNormalization(),
            layers.LeakyReLU(0.2),
            layers.Conv2D(256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
            layers.BatchNormalization(),
            layers.LeakyReLU(0.2),
            layers.Conv2D(1, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding="same"),
            layers.Activation("sigmoid")
        ])

    def call(self, x):
        # Resize the input image to a fixed size
        x = self.resize(x)
        
        # Pass the resized image through the discriminator model
        return self.model(x)

def train(dataset, generator, discriminator, autoencoder_encoder, epochs):
#.....
 for epoch in range(epochs):
        epoch_start_time = time.time()  # Track the epoch start time
        total_gen_loss = 0
        total_disc_loss = 0
        total_fjd_value = 0
        
        for step, (img_with_screws, img_without_screws, mask) in enumerate(dataset):
          generator.save(os.path.join(weights_file_path, f"generator_epoch_{epoch + 1}.keras"))
        discriminator.save(os.path.join(weights_file_path, f"discriminator_epoch_{epoch + 1}.keras"))
#....

def test_for_epochs(dataset_with_screw_eval, dataset_no_screw_eval, masked_screws_eval, output_folder, generator_model_path):
    # Ensure the output folder exists
    os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

    # Load evaluation dataset
    eval_dataset = load_dataset(dataset_with_screw_eval, dataset_no_screw_eval, masked_screws_eval, shuffle=False)
    eval_dataset = eval_dataset.batch(1)  # Process one image at a time

    # Convert dataset to list and check if it's empty
    eval_dataset_list = list(eval_dataset)
    if len(eval_dataset_list) == 0:
        raise ValueError("Evaluation dataset is empty, cannot continue.")
    print(f"Dataset loaded with {len(eval_dataset_list)} samples.")

    # Randomly select one sample
    selected_sample = random.choice(eval_dataset_list)
    img_with_screws, img_without_screws, mask = selected_sample

    # Save reference images for visualization
    reference_img_np = (tf.squeeze(img_with_screws[0]) * 255).numpy().astype(np.uint8)  # Rescale to [0, 255]
    plt.imsave(os.path.join(output_folder, "reference_image_with_screws.png"), reference_img_np, cmap='gray')

    reference_mask_np = (tf.squeeze(mask[0]) * 255).numpy().astype(np.uint8)  # Rescale to [0, 255]
    plt.imsave(os.path.join(output_folder, "reference_mask.png"), reference_mask_np, cmap='gray')

    original_np = (tf.squeeze(img_without_screws[0]) * 255).numpy().astype(np.uint8)
    plt.imsave(os.path.join(output_folder, "reference_image_with_no_screws.png"), original_np, cmap='gray')

    custom_objects = {
            'MaskedSelfAttention': MaskedSelfAttention,  # Custom layer
            'Conv2D': tf.keras.layers.Conv2D,            # Standard Conv2D layer
            'BatchNormalization': tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization,  # Standard BatchNormalization layer
            'Generator': Generator
            }

    for i in range(1, 101):
    # Load the generator model
        
        # Load the generator model for a specific epoch (e.g., epoch 1)
        model_file = f"generator_epoch_{i}.keras"
        model_path = os.path.join(generator_model_path, model_file)

        # Load the model with custom objects
        generator = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path, custom_objects=custom_objects)
        print(f"Generator model for epoch {i} loaded.")
        

        for layer in generator.layers:
           if not layer.built:
              layer.build(generator.input_shape)  # Ensure each layer is built

        generator.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
        
        # Generate an image using the loaded generator
        input_img = tf.concat([img_with_screws, mask], axis=-1)  # Concatenate input with mask
        generated_img = generator.predict_on_batch(input_img)  # Generate image
        print(f"Image modified by generator for epoch {i}.")
#.....

# Main execution
if __name__ == "__main__":
    batch_size = 8
    #mode = 'train'
    mode = 'test'

    #Autoencoder for fjd metric
    autoencoder_model_path = os.path.expanduser('....../autoencoder_model_final.keras')
    autoencoder = tf.keras.models.load_model(autoencoder_model_path)

    # Extract the encoder part of the autoencoder
    autoencoder_encoder = tf.keras.Model(inputs=autoencoder.input, outputs=autoencoder.get_layer('flatten').output)

    generator = Generator()
    discriminator = Discriminator()

    # build has just to be done once
    # Before saving the model, ensure it is built with the correct input shape
    generator.build(input_shape=(None, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 1))  # For Generator
    
    # no need to build the disc since it has no custom layers
    #discriminator.build(input_shape=(None, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 1))  # For Discriminator

    learning_rate = 0.0001
    generator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.99)
    discriminator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.99)


    if mode == 'train':
        train_dataset = load_dataset(dataset_with_screw_train, dataset_no_screw_train, masked_screws_train, shuffle=True)
        train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
        train(train_dataset, generator=generator, discriminator=discriminator, autoencoder_encoder=autoencoder_encoder, epochs=100)
        #mode = 'eval'
    
    elif mode == 'test':
        #generator_model_path = os.path.join(weights_file_path, f"generator_epoch_{chosen_epoch}.keras")  # Use the saved model
        eval_dataset = load_dataset(dataset_with_screw_eval, dataset_no_screw_eval, masked_screws_eval, shuffle=False)  # Ensure no shuffling
        test_for_epochs(dataset_with_screw_eval, dataset_no_screw_eval, masked_screws_eval, output_folder_test, weights_file_path)

I tried different methods of loading in the models and could break down the number of not included objects from 9 to 4 but cant find where the last 4s problem come from. This is the summary of the Generator architecture:
Generator Summary
